# Bad symbolic reference with discord4j

Tags: java, scala-3, discord4j

I'm trying to use `discord4j 3.2` and slash command in `scala 3` code. When I added the code for slash command, `sbt` gave me this error when compiling:

```
[error] Bad symbolic reference. A signature
[error] refers to Value/T in package org.immutables.value which is not available.
[error] It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
[error] the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling the signature.
[warn] Caught: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: failure to resolve inner class:
[warn] externalName = org.immutables.value.Value$Immutable,
[warn] outerName = org.immutables.value.Value,
[warn] innerName = Immutable
[warn] owner.fullName = org.immutables.value.Value
[warn] while parsing ~/.cache/coursier/v1/https/oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/discord4j/discord-json/1.6.10-SNAPSHOT/discord-json-1.6.10-20210908.025209-4.jar(discord4j/discordjson/json/InteractionApplicationCommandCallbackData.class) while parsing annotations in ~/.cache/coursier/v1/https/oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/discord4j/discord-json/1.6.10-SNAPSHOT/discord-json-1.6.10-20210908.025209-4.jar(discord4j/discordjson/json/InteractionApplicationCommandCallbackData.class)
[error] Bad symbolic reference. A signature
```

I have no issues compiling code creating slash command using the same version of `discord4j` but in `scala 2` code.

Here's my `sbt` file:

```scala
val scala3Version = "3.0.2"

val scala2deps = Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.6.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-typed" % "2.6.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.6.8",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.2.0",

  "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.2.29",

  "io.projectreactor" %% "reactor-scala-extensions" % "0.8.+",

  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.+",

  "com.lihaoyi" %% "requests" % "0.2.0",
).map(d ⇒ d.cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13))

lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "PUGBot",
    version := "0.1.0",

    scalacOptions ++= Seq(
      "-language:postfixOps",
      "-language:implicitConversions",
      ),


    scalaVersion := scala3Version,

    resolvers += "d4j-snapshot" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots",

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.discord4j" % "discord4j-core" % "3.2.0-RC3",
    ) ++ scala2deps,

  )
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: These kinds of errors usually suggest that you are trying to compile Scala 3 with an old version of `sbt`. Make sure you are using the latest.

Comment: BEWARE: [json4s is vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks!](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue with de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo 3.0.0 and Scala 3.0.2:

```
scalac: Bad symbolic reference. A signature
refers to Value/T in package org.immutables.value which is not available.
It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling the signature.
```

```
scalac: Caught: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: failure to resolve inner class:
externalName = org.immutables.value.Value$Immutable,
outerName = org.immutables.value.Value,
innerName = Immutable
owner.fullName = org.immutables.value.Value
while parsing /Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/de/flapdoodle/embed/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo/3.0.0/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-3.0.0.jar(de/flapdoodle/embed/mongo/config/MongodConfig.class) while parsing annotations in /Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/de/flapdoodle/embed/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo/3.0.0/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-3.0.0.jar(de/flapdoodle/embed/mongo/config/MongodConfig.class)
```

I have added `org.immutables.value` library as Sbt dependency and it helped:

```
"org.immutables" % "value" % "2.8.8"
```